# Error with reading font

Tags: csv, character-encoding

I have a problem with Korean file csv. It can't be read.
It shows like below:

```
%s has been added to your bag., %s ? ??? ?????? ???????
```

Could someone help me to resolve it?

Comment: What are you attempting to load it IN? Supplying the file might also assist.

Comment: Fonts? ... do you perhaps mean characters? . The problem may be the **character encoding**. Try choosing -or setting **UTF-8** as character encoding (charset), then import (or open, or load) it into your program.